# You are not authorized to respond to this item

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I am programmatically trying to delegate the sharepoint 2013 workflow task to  "DOMAIN\Test2" user from "DOMAIN\Test1" user. Its delegating to "DOMAIN\Test2" user but when I try to access the task item url using the delegated user("DOMAIN\Test2") account, I am getting the below error:

**"You are not authorized to respond to this item."**

```
using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("http://tst:001/sites/Test"))
    {
        using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
        {

            string tasksList = "Workflow Tasks";                    
            SPUser delegateTouser = currentWeb.EnsureUser("DOMAIN\\Test2");
            SPListItem listItem = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(tasksList).GetItemById(101);
            listItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo] = delegateTouser;
            listItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = "1";
            listItem.Update();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the message you are getting? It's not even correct English...

Comment: You are right. Message is not same but similar to, meaning that the user does not have atleast even view permission.

Comment: Well what is the EXACT message? Without that, it may not be possible for us to help.

Comment: I have modified the message.

Answer (score 0):

Use RunWithElevatedPrivileges when you open a site:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){
using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("http://tst:001/sites/Test"))
{
    using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
    {

        string tasksList = "Workflow Tasks";                    
        SPUser delegateTouser = currentWeb.EnsureUser("DOMAIN\\Test2");
        SPListItem listItem = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(tasksList).GetItemById(101);
        listItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo] = delegateTouser;
        listItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = "1";
        listItem.Update();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Rather than wrapping the `using (SPSite...` stuff in a RWEP block, instantiate the `SPSite` with a second parameter in the constructor - `SPUserToken.SystemAccount`. This will let you perform what you need to do as the system account without using the sledgehammer of reverting the process identity to the app pool identity.